# Index null values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, null, laravel-scout

I am indexing my data to ElasticSearch using(laravel-scout), and some fields have `null value`..
I know Elastic would ignore fields that are `empty` or `null`.. so I just need to check existence of that fields.
but when I return my search results I see that all data of that specific field return to `null`... even somewhere I know that my field have value.. but still returns `null`!

is anyone can tell me why this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your search query and 2 documents for example, one with null and the second with value

Comment: I updated my index, and my problem solved.. thanks.